# Center a div vertically with an animation

Tags: jquery, animation, center

I would like to center the `.presentation` div vertically but with an animation. A displacement from bottom to top of 10%.

I need to keep the possibility to put different height value to the parent's div `.parent` like 75% or 100% but that my text stay centered vertically.

Can I have some help please ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/4t9vsym3/2/

```
$('.presentation').animate({
    top: '40%',
    opacity: '1'
}, 1700, function () {});
```

```
.parent {
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.presentation {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The flaw in your code is that you try to approximate the deviation of the top of the text by 10% (50% - 10% = 40%). Instead should calculate this deviation by `$('.presentation').outerHeight() / 2`
Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4t9vsym3/3/).

There i put the text directly under the div in which it should be centered and then let it animate up by `($('.parent').outerHeight() - $('.presentation').outerHeight()) / 2` 
which equals

```
$('.parent').outerHeight()/2 - $('.presentation').outerHeight() / 2
```

(I additionally set `overflow:hidden` css-property to .parent)

**EDIT:**

I readjusted the calculation using h2-top and height as reference.. now it's centered regardless of the content

```
var $par = $('.parent');
var $pres = $('.presentation');
var initTop = $par.offset().top + $par.height() * 0.9;

$pres.offset({left: $pres.offset().left , top : initTop});
var delta = $pres.find('h2').offset().top - ($par.offset().top + ($par.height() - $pres.find('h2').height()) / 2);
$pres.animate({
    top: '-=' + delta,
    opacity: '1'
}, 1700, function () {});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4t9vsym3/9/

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately the text don't stay centered when I add text : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/4t9vsym3/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use css transform to offset the text's position by half its height:

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Eg: http://jsfiddle.net/4t9vsym3/6/

P.S `.parent` should be `position:relative` in order for `.presentation` to be correctly positioned within it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do some quick height calculations.

The top position of your element should be:

```
( heightOfParent - heightOfCenteredElement ) / 2
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/urmg48ba/

EDIT: fiddle was broken. Updated.